# How can I change version of Excel which is used by Visual Studio to debug?

Tags: c#, excel, vsto

I have 3 versions of MS Excel installed on my PC. I am developing some VSTO Tool. VS debugger fires currently MS Excel 2013. What should I do to force VS to debug tool in other version of MS Excel?

Comment: Just make sure that you have added reference of that perticular version of interop ddl.

Answer (score 1):

Replace the interop reference with the target version and use the *Start external program* option in the Properties window as shown below:

[image]

Specify the path to the target Office Excel version.

Comment: your image is broken.